# Do I have to pay double for checked baggage?

Tags: airports, easyjet, payment

I'm planning a holiday for a week to Spain with EasyJet. It's much cheaper to pay for my suitcase allowance online and I was wondering how it works. What I mean is, as it is a round-trip, I have to pay twice. So doing it online, would I be charged double and is it all just a one-time payment?

I plan on going to other countries as well so it would be useful to know how paying online works and in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pay for each direction, so if it's a return flight, you'll pay two sets of checked baggage fees.

Separate flights on other tickets will have separate fees as well.

Comment: So the total overall when i pay would be doubled

Comment: if i however go over i’m guessing i would pay at the airport?

Comment: @gully0923 Oversized and overweight baggage will be subject to additional fees, and yes, you'll pay those at the airport unless you've pre-declared them when doing online checkin (and paid then).

Comment: If you book through the easyjet website, it will tell you the price per flight of a bag, but if you add a bag it also says "Total price for all flights", which is how much the total price goes up by.

Comment: @djr so all flights meaning there and back

Comment: @gully0923 To be clear, you're not paying double, you're paying for *each flight*, two in your case.

Comment: @gully0923 Yes, if you're booking flights there and back then the total for all flights will be 2 x the price per flight, because you're booking a bag for the flight there and one for the flight back.

Comment: With EasyJet, if you want luggage only one way, you will have to buy two separate tickets, so yes you pay both directions at once, twice the luggage per flight fee.